# How to limit the max length of a sorted set when I run zadd concurrently?

Tags: concurrency, redis

I want to use redis to store data like this: `{id: timestamp(1416991171)}` in a sorted set, and it need to have a max length.

I just check the length of the sorted set before I insert a new member/value pair.But I'm not sure if this's a good idea to ensure the max length because I'll run it concurrently.

The code is like this(in ruby):

```
key = "list"
max = 5
if $redis.zcard(key) < max
  $redis.zadd(key, Time.now.to_i, "foo")
end
```

How can I ensure the max length? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Note: it looks like your question has a typo as you're using the `key` twice - once for the sorted set and once as your identifier. I've referred to the identifier as `keyx` in my reply.</strike>

You have two options to ensure that your Sorted Set doesn't grow above the `max`, namely use Redis' [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) or [server-side Lua scripts](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL). Both approaches will ensure the workflow's atomicity (although personally, I prefer the latter).

Using the transactional approach, you'd probably do something like the following pseudo-Ruby code:

```
key = "list"
max = 5
$redis.watch key
if $redis.zcard(key) < max
  $redis.multi
  $redis.zadd(key, Time.now.to_i, "foo")
  $redis.exec
else
  $redis.unwatch key
end
```

Alternatively, with a script:

```
key = "list"
max = 5
s = <<EOF
if redis.call('ZCARD', KEYS[1]) < ARGV[1] then
   redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[2], ARGV[3])
end
EOF
$redis.eval s, 1, key, max, Time.now.to_i, "foo"
```